# phpspec creates files in wrong folders per psr-4 namespace specification

Tags: php, autoload, phpspec, psr-4

I scrapped the earlier form of my question because it was too convoluted. Here's the new version.

I want to use phpspec with my psr-4 formatted projects.

Here's the way I tried to set up a test project:

1. Created a new folder for the project:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop/
   mkdir TestPhpSpec
   cd TestPhpSpec
   ```
2. create a new `composer.json` file and require phpspec:

   ```
   composer require phpspec/phpspec
   ```

Which creates my `composer.json` file:

```
    {
        "require": {
            "phpspec/phpspec": "^2.3"
        }
    }
```

3. I add my psr-4 namespace to the autoload property of my `composer.json` file:

   ```
   {
       "require": {
           "phpspec/phpspec": "^2.3"
       },
       "autoload": {
           "psr-4": {
               "Acme\\": "src/Acme"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Then I dump my autoload to make sure my namespace is loaded: `composer dumpautoload`
5. After that, I create my `phpspec.yml` to describe the namespace to phpspec:

   ```
   suites:
     acme_suite:
         namespace: Acme
         psr4_prefix: Acme
   ```
6. Then I describe the class I want to start building:

   ```
   phpspec describe Acme/Markdown
   ```

This is where I run into the first problem. Even though I specify the Acme namespace in my `describe` command, the spec does not get placed in a folder matching the namespace:

[image: Incorrect namespaced spec]

Though the class it creates is namespaced correctly:

```
<?php

namespace spec\Acme; // correct namespace

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class MarkdownSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('Acme\Markdown');
    }
}
```

Then if I try to run the test to start TDD-ing.

```
    phpspec run
```

It offers to create the class for me and I let it. From there I get the second problem; I get the error message:

> [PhpSpec\Process\Prerequisites\PrerequisiteFailedException]
>   The type Acme\Markdown was generated but could not be loaded. Do you need to configure an autoloader?

[image]

And the class it creates is not in it's namespaced folder:

[image: incorrect namespaced class]

The class it creates is also namespaced correctly:

```
<?php

namespace Acme; // correct namespace

class Markdown
{
}
```

I've looked over the docs and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
suites:
  acme_suite:
      src_path: Acme/src
      spec_path: Acme/spec
```

Comment: I gave that a try. Now my specs are being created in an Acme namespace folder at the root level (I don't mind that), but when I run the spec and I'm asked if I would like it to create the class it is still being put at the root level of my `src` folder. The class created has the correct namespace declaration, but it's not in the right namespaced folder and phpspec still can't autoload the class :/

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz are you sure you need to specify both namespace/psr4_prefix in configuration and in composer? I'm not sure about that...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure (still tying to learn how to use phpspec), but I would suspect you do need both. I need it in composer for the project autoloading, and the phpspec docs have a specific section about [using psr-4 with phpspec](http://phpspec.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/configuration.html#psr-4). That said, I'll give it a try really quick without the suite specification.

Comment: holy...shit... I just emptied my phpspec.yml file, deleted all of the invalid spec and src files, did a whole new `desc` and `run` and it worked. I can't believe I burned so much time trying to configure this when it doesn't need it * *facepalm* *. Thank you SO MUCH for helping me figure this out!

Comment: So this is the solution without any modification?

Comment: Well, the solution is that you don't seem to need the psr-4 configuration at all for phpspec. I think the doc page I linked may have been for a previous version ( I don't see any kind of version information on the page, though the google search leading me in said it was for v 2.1 and I'm using 2.3).

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz so you removed it from composer.json and you left the file as I wrote it here?

Comment: Other way around, I left the psr-4 autoload in the composer.json file and removed suite information from the phpspec.yml file. The correct solution coming from when you asked "are you sure you need to specify both namespace/psr4_prefix in configuration and in composer?" and the answer being "no, you only need it in `composer.json` apparently".

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz yes, because I didn't noticed that you had setted it into composer.json; i'll update my answer :)

Comment: Try this =>$vendor/bin/phpspec run

Comment: I didn't get it working even after doing above mentioned, until I did that popular `composer dumpautoload`